# Stripping out < and > in javascript doesn't quite work

Tags: javascript

```
    function SanitizeInput(input) {



        input = input.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
        input = input.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");


        return input;
    }

document.write(SanitizeInput("Test!<marquee>bibble</marquee>"));
```

If you pop this into jsfiddle.net the result is `Test!<marquee>bibble</marquee` without the trailing >

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Replacing it with ( and ) seems to work perfectly

Comment: You may need to escape the `<`, I'm not sure. But what are you trying to do with this? I can well be wrong, but this whole operation smells wrong to me.

Comment: Correction, no `<` and `>` do not need to be escaped in Javascript regexes. Strange.

Comment: Prevent users from entering html into a textbox...

Comment: jsFiddle with escaping, works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/CNNrT/

Comment: Could e a quirk of jsfiddle as I copied and pasted the above into a html document and it produced the expected result...

Comment: What are you doing with the text after it's entered in the textbox?  Seems like you should just be encoding it (ideally on the server) before you display it.

Comment: This is part of a pure javascript page, the user enters information into a textbox and presses a button, it stores the value in a javascript array. Repeat until editing is done, then send the final result to the server. The inputs are displayed client side both in html and in textboxes, so pure javascript is required - not just for security, but to stop the client mangling the page up by typing ' or "

Comment: Reproducible in WebKit and Firefox but not Opera http://jsfiddle.net/gsj6L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The function you use does replace all your `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Just that document.write adds the sanitized text to the HTML document and the entities get converted back to `<` and `>`.

Just try `alert` instead of `document.write`.

If you really want to have `&lt;` visible in your page you should "double-sanitize" the text.

```
input = input.replace(/</g, "&amp;lt;");
```

On a side note you could chain replace calls, like this:

```
input = input.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Hope you find this useful,
Alin

Answer (score 3):

There has to be something else in your layout/document affecting this, your code itself works fine, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NBdH6/).

Comment: @jleedev - `document.write` doesn't work reliably outside inline script at all...it's just an example I believe.

Comment: @jleedev - Yeah...you can't use `document.write` like that...*where* would you be writing it?  The function itself works, here's your version with an alert instead: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gsj6L/1/

Comment: @Nick Yes, I was mainly trying to read the OP’s mind. Using `document.write` in that way *is* well-defined in HTML5, though. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#document.write

Comment: @jleedev - This well-defined way will write the content after `</html>`, that wasn't the W3C's intent on *how it should be used*, they're just keeping the behavior consistent when it *is* used that way by specifying it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to sanitize input, try something like this - http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/